# Create dashboard setting which lets me set ID of category which is inserted into template

Tags: customization, theme-options, dashboard

Part of a function i'm using in my single.php page is

`$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 10, 'offset' => 0,'post_status'=>'publish','category' => 32));`

I need to make the number `32` dynamic so it can be set from the dashboard

I'm familiar with advanced custom fields for posts. Is there a similar plugin that would let me create custom options? Or can someone suggest a good modern tutorial on creating a basic option like this in the dashboard

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin that let me create custom options and set the value dynamically in my templates. Worked out fine

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-options-plus/

Comment: IMHO not really useful to set categories ID, once you migrate all the IDs wil change, it will be sorted out.You can try pass the category name and use `get_term_by()`.

Comment: Well that's my reason for making it dynamic so that on a new server it can be set dynamically from the dashboard.